# Limit PostgreSQL SELECT to number result ony

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple SELECT with GROUP BY request who return what I want, but even more...

I want to limit the result to number only.

For exemple, if my request return:

```
01,02,aa,03,04,ab,05
```

I only want:

```
01,02,03,04,05
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple regex pattern match to see if it only contains digits:

```
s ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```

where `s` is your column name. Just drop that check in your `WHERE` clause

Example:

```
SELECT s FROM (VALUES ('00'), ('aa'), ('0a')) x (s) WHERE s ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```

only gives back `00`.